# Matrix Representation of Quantum Channels

Tags: quantum-operation

I am working on a project and I expect to have expressions of a bunch of quantum channels of interest. The quantum channels will be in matrix form. For example for a 2 qubit system, the quantum channel will be given by a 16 by 16 matrix.

Is there any systematic way to use the matrix representations of quantum channels and find the corresponding Kraus operators etc? Find which channels correspond to unitary channels etc?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5816/13968

Comment: There are multiple representations of channels using a single, necessarily square matrix, most notably the _Choi_ and $\chi$ matrix. See e.g. [this previous answer of mine](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/how-to-perform-quantum-process-tomography-for-three-qubit-gates/11691#11691). For both these we have: **1)** the eigenvectors correspond to the Kraus operators and **2)** if the matrix is single rank it corresponds to a unitary. If you let us know what representation you will work with I can write up a more detailed answer.

Comment: you can also find a bunch of explicit examples of matrix representations (with a focus on Chois and Stinespring isometries) in https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24511/55. Does any of these linked posts answer your question? If not, could you further clarify what you are asking and how it differs from the other related discussions?

Comment: I have yet to perform the computation but I expect to have a bunch of matrices in the usual sense. I'll have to throw away the matrices that don't correspond to CPTP maps. I'll then like to identify the remaining matrices/CPTP maps with their Kraus and/or Choi decomposition.

Comment: @user22511 that still doesn't clarify the problem. There are multiple possible matrix representations of a channel. You need to specify which one you are talking about.

Comment: Well I am first trying to classify using representation theory certain matrices that meet some commutation relations. For a 2 qubit system, I'll have 16 by 16 matrices representing some linear maps taking 4 by 4 matrices to 4 by 4 matrices. I'll then have to throw those away that are not representing CPTP maps.

Comment: Does this help? It's just linear algebra at this point. After this point, I need to start interpreting everything in terms of quantum channels so I'd like to convert the *CPTP matrices* to their Kraus/Choi representations.