# Struggling with going from Choi matrix to the Choi-Kraus decomposition by eiegen-decomposition of the Choi matrix

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, kraus-representation

I found going from the Choi-matrix of a quantum channel to the Choi-Kraus decomposition a bit difficult. I know that it follows from the eigen-decomposition of the Choi-matrix. But I struggle with both how this is done and how we derive the Kraus operators from this, both in the case of general channels and for specific channels.

I have tried to do this with the of "Amplitude damping channel" and end up with the Choi matrix
$$
C_{N_{\gamma}}=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &0 &0 &\sqrt{1-\gamma}\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&\gamma&0\\\sqrt{1-\gamma}&0&0&1-\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But I don't know how to procede from here.

Any answers, general tips and where to read more would be appreciated.

Comment: Do these help? Or are you looking for something even more explicit? [Question1](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5804/how-does-the-vectorization-map-relate-to-the-choi-and-kraus-representations-of-a), [Question2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/694874/finding-the-kraus-operators-of-a-quantum-channel-from-its-choi-matrix)

Comment: I think I am more unsure about the actual spectral decomposing. How would i go about decomposing the matrix above?